# How can I determine whether the current process has a UI open?

Tags: c++, c

I am writing some library code which will rerun the current process as an administrator/root. The problem is (for linux at least) that if the calling code is a command line application the best way would be to call sudo whereas if it is a gui application, gksudo is appropriate. For completeness sake though, solutions (or pointers to solutions) for other os's are also welcome.

Also, this is useful so that for GUI apps, I can turn off printf statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run `gksu(do)` if the environment variable `DISPLAY` is set. It doesn't really matter if the application has a GUI or not, if there's an X-server running, and we can use it, why shouldn't we?

Doesn't allow you to determine if you should disable stdout output. However, stderr output is generally captured in .xsession-errors, even if no terminal is connected, so you might not want to disable that output afterall.

Comment: the cognitive burden of going back and forth between mouse and keyboard sucks (not to mention that it is just plain slower) and I want to avoid it as much as possible. in any case, it still doesnt address the other situations you would want to know if there is a UI.

Comment: honestly, I'm working on the installer for an application and I need sudo to install. Its an annoyance to me because every time I fix a bug in the installer i need to rerun, etc.

Comment: When it runs normally, it shouldnt have root privledges, only the first time for install.

Comment: I mean in your development setup (or better, just use a chroot or something, where you wont need root privileges, and disable the privilege elevation stuff), the 'real' installation could run gksudo if display is set, and I don't think it'll bother anyone. Also, unset DISPLAY in your setup, and presto, no more gksudo :)